# Eloquent Relationship on the same model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using the User model and want to reference other users on a One to Many relationship.

With two models, this would be done by a Many to Many but this attempt at it is obviously wrong:

```
public function relatedUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'related_user', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Is there a better way I can achieve my goal? I don't need an inverse method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasMany()` or `belongsTo()` (according to your need) relation for same model relationship

Define hasMany relationship in User model:

```
public function relatedUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany('User','user_id');
}
```

Example:
Consider you have one User object

```
$user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
```

If you want to access related records

```
$related_users = $user->relatedUsers; // this will return all related users for particular object
```